# How do I make an animation grow and then stay that size?

Tags: android, android-animation

I can't seem to make an animation grow then stay that size for another animation.  I have tried `android:fillEnabled="true"` & `android:fillAfter="true"` but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a guess that you are using xml animations, which are acting on drawables. 
The second animation is going to use the same drawable values available to the first animation (these values don't actually change, which is why the second animation doesn't work as expected), the best way I would go about this is to dynamically make each animation in code, there by having reference to all values / attributes changed in each animation

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

should give a good over view of how to do this dynamically